# What is the best is the best OAuth grant to use in developing a front-end only app

Tags: php, laravel-5, oauth-2.0

I am very new to OAuth and I intend implementing an api for a frontend only (html and JavaScript) web app with login abilities using laravel Passport. Both the frontend app and the API server will reside on different servers. I have read a lot about different grants but still confused about which will be best suited for what I intend doing. Are the access tokens going to be stored on the front end (using local storage or cookies)? I am just confused about where to even start from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the Implicit grant which is designed for browser applications. You can keep tokens in the [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) (or the localStorage if you want to share them among browser tabs). OAuth2 tokens should sent as `Authorization: Bearer tokenstring` HTTP request headers, so cookies are not a good place for storing them.

There are two token types you can use:

- Access token - if you want to use the token for authentication, access tokens hold scopes - information what actions the client is allowed to perform on behalf the person who was authenticated. Access tokens are often just random strings, so to validate it, the backend needs to ask the `/token` endpoint to get info about their validity and about the person who authenticated it.
- [ID token](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken) from OpenID Connect (OAuth2 extension) - in JWT form, ID tokens hold info about the person who authenticated them, can be validate offline, but cannot be used for authorization - they don't hold any scopes.

Bot token types have limited lifetime, you will have to get new token before the original one expires (using `&prompt=none` request see the [OpenID Connect RFC](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest)).

Comment: Thanks a lot Jan, your reply was spot on. My greatest challenge was not knowing where to store the tokens as I thought easy proliferation of localStorage will be a set back. Thanks once again.